# R - time series decomposition without detection of seasonality

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series dataset with 200 data points. I have decomposed it using the function below:

```
dat2 = ts(dat1, frequency = 4)
decomposeDat = decompose(dat2, "multiplicative")
```

I get 4 components: trend, seasonal, cyclic and irregularity. But when I check if there is seasonality present in the dataset with frequency "4", Rstudio says that there is no seasonality for this frequency. The check is performed with the following code:

```
dat2 = ts(dat1, frequency = 4)
fit <- tbats(dat2)
seasonal <- !is.null(fit$seasonal)
seasonal
```

seasonal returns FALSE meaning that there is no seasonality with frequency 4.

Can someone explain, why can I decompose it into a seasonality component when no seasonality is present from the check mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your data it is hard to tell whether there is seasonality or not. The `decompose()` function will try to find seasonality using a different approach than `tbats()` as discussed in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55716/interpreting-time-series-decomposition-using-tbats-from-r-forecast-package) and the user comments of [this blog post by the author of tbats](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/).

I would recommend to post your data and discuss what you are trying to achieve to get more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge it decomposes the time series to a seasonal component as well since you specify it, that the seasonality is 4. Moreover, you could check the seasonality with 4 using the [TStools](https://github.com/trnnick/TStools) (seasplot() function), it will provide you with a p-value of how significant is that seasonality, which seems more informative than a TRUE or a FALSE.